# MySQL Create DB/User from Batch File

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I am trying to setup an install script (batch file) that will automatically create a MYSQL database and a user when we install a service, assign the user to the DB, then run the install .sql file.

Would this be correct?

```
@echo off
c:\mysql\bin\mysql < CREATE DATABASE hlstats;
c:\mysql\bin\mysql < CREATE USER 'username_here'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here';
c:\mysql\bin\mysql < GRANT ALL ON hlstats.* TO 'username_here'@'localhost';
c:\mysql\bin\mysql < install.sql
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run those scripts with mysql other parameters. Initial 3 scripts should be run as root user as most of cases. So, command format should be like below:

mysql -uroot -p < CREATE DATABASE hlstats;

Then for install.sql as long as i believe you need to create tables inside htstats database as username_here. you need to pass those parameters with mysql command as below:

mysql -uusername_here -ppassword_here hlstats< install.sql

Answer (score 0):

Run `mysql` with [-e option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute):

```
mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE hlstats'
```

.. and check exit code on each step.